# Use a CSS Class to Style an Element

Tags: css

I'm currently learning how to code on freecodecamp.com, and I'm having difficulty successfully using a CSS class to a style an element. Specifically, changing the text CatPhotoApp from red to blue.  I've followed the instructions on the page, and this is what I've done so far:

```
<style>
  h2 {.blue-text
  color: blue;
  }
</style>

<h2>CatPhotoApp</h2>

<p>Kitty ipsum dolor sit amet, shed everywhere shed everywhere stretching   attack your ankles chase the red dot, hairball run catnip eat the grass sniff.</p>
```

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Or, say `.blue-text { color: blue; }`, and then write `<h2 class="blue-text">`.

Comment: @j08691 i think he needs the class "blue-text"

Comment: @Mango - Why do you think that?

Comment: @j08691 because he wants to style the h2 element with the text "CatPhotoApp" (by changing its color to blue) and if he removes the class he cannot do that.

Comment: @Mango - Why not? The `<h2>` example in the question has no class. You can start a chat with me if you'd like to discuss this further.

Comment: @j08691 I do not have enough privileges to start a chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To bind styling to the class you have to define "who" is the class:

```
<h2></h2>
```

Has no class.

```
<h2 class="classname"></h2>
```

Has the class(the class is classname)

The styling can you define by:

```
<style>
  .classname{
   color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

Have a nice day!

You can scope h2 and class in styling - this way:

```
<style>
  h2.classname{
   color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

You can bind 2 classes to (fe) h2:

```
<h2 class="blue-text bigtext"></h2>
```

This has 2 classes (blue-text and bigtext), the styling is concated.

```
<style>
  .blue-text{
   color: blue;
  }
  .bigtext{
   font-size: 1000%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! That certainly helps!

Answer (score 2):

there is no class `.blue-text`, so just remove it from your css

```css
h2 {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<h2>CatPhotoApp</h2>

<p>Kitty ipsum dolor sit amet, shed everywhere shed everywhere stretching attack your ankles chase the red dot, hairball run catnip eat the grass sniff.</p>
```

if you want and/or need to apply `.blue-text` to your `h2` then here is how:

```css
.blue-text {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<h2 class="blue-text">CatPhotoApp</h2>

<p>Kitty ipsum dolor sit amet, shed everywhere shed everywhere stretching attack your ankles chase the red dot, hairball run catnip eat the grass sniff.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to style the this element with a class, you must add the class attribute and correct the css like this:

```
<style>
  .blue-text{
  color: blue;
  }
</style>

<h2 class="blue-text">CatPhotoApp</h2>

<p>Kitty ipsum dolor sit amet, shed everywhere shed everywhere stretching attack your ankles chase the red dot, hairball run catnip eat the grass sniff.</p>
```